# Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : invalid 'description' argument Called from: gzfile(file, "rb")

Tags: r, config, rds, gzip

I have a problem with a function I have made trying to map some columns with config file I have made. I am running the function yet I get the error:

```
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : invalid 'description' argument Called        from: gzfile(file, "rb")
```

I have looked online, including stack overflow and do not get a proper answer to this question. Would you please help?
This functions I have made works well on another machine but as I tried to deploy my work onto my personal laptop, it seems I get this error.

This is what I am attempting to do in Mac:

Thinking of the the path is set to this:

```
 data_import_list <- list(list(data_path = "Users/gb/Rprojects/data/data.csv", 
                               config_path = "Users/gb/Rprojects/lgt-config/inp/"))
```

And then I read it with the function

```
import_col_types <- function(config_path){
  column_mapping <- readRDS(file.path(config_path, "column_mapping.rds")) 

  # get list of config files 
  config_file_list <- Sys.glob(paste0(config_path, "*.rds"))
}
```

Actually this is how I read with the above function:

```
import_col_types(data_import_list)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: hello blackbrandt, this is a huge work that is also confidential. Will try to give more info but that means I should rebuild the whole architecture with the renamed functions and a fake dataset. This took me months to create and I am afraid it is a huge whole work.

Comment: Your `data_import_list` is a list of lists, and you pass it through `import_col_types` and it ends up in `file.path`, and that will construct an invalid path that you feed to `readRDS`. I'm guessing you really want to get a component of that list.

Comment: @Spacedman this is just a snipet of an entire code and kind of impossible to share it as this is confidential. Thank you so much for your help. Plus, the code works fine on my PC but not on my laptop (Mac) if this helps.

Comment: There's **no way** we can debug code that we can't see. The best we can do is say "something is wrong with the `file.path` constructed and fed to `readRDS`". Do that one line in two steps - first construct the path, then print that, then try the readRDS. Check the printed path is correct. Getting "invalid description argument" can happen in specific situations but we cannot work out what those are. In my answer I've already suggested you print the file name out and check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Print out `file` before the error. Check it is what you think it is. I can replicate your error message with:

```
> gzfile(1,"rb")
Error in gzfile(1, "rb") : invalid 'description' argument
> gzfile(NA,"rb")
Error in gzfile(NA, "rb") : invalid 'description' argument
> gzfile(NULL,"rb")
Error in gzfile(NULL, "rb") : invalid 'description' argument
```

but not:

```
> gzfile("nonexist","rb")
Error in gzfile("nonexist", "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile("nonexist", "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'nonexist', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

so it looks like your `file` is broken. No way we can see what it is, so you need to debug this yourself. Basic debugging.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the relevant lines of code there, nicely formatted, and include the error message **at the point in your code where it occurs**

Comment: thank you for everything. I have debug and the path was incorrect. Thank you!